# Serializing POCO class derived from baseclass with DataContract?

Tags: json.net

I noticed that when serializing/deserializing a POCO class with JSON.NET that derives from a base class that uses explicit DataContract attributes then any POCO properties on the derived class are ignored.

For example, in this example, "Address" is not serialized/deserialized:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyBaseClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SomeName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Is that intentional?

FWIW, it does seem that DataContractSerializer (at least the XML one) does the "right thing" here and serializes/deserializes "Address".

Thanks!

Henrik

Comment: In my testing, the `DataContractSerializer` will not serialize the subclass at all if it is not decorated with `[DataContract]`; instead it throws an exception.  This seems to be consistent with the [documentation for the `DataContractAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx), which states that it is not inherited from the base class.

Comment: @BrianRogers Did you mean the base class needs the attribute? Anyway, it's been a while so maybe it changed.  See [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx#Anchor_1) for how inheritance affects data contracts.

Answer (score 2):

In JSON.NET, at least as of v4.5.6, it detects the `DataContract` of the base class and [assumes opt-in serialization](http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/357850). Since `Address` is not decorated with the `DataMember` attribute it does not get serialized.

This is by design according to James Newton-King with no planned change.

Comment: Not part of my answer, but my opinion is that this is a bad implementation in JSON.NET. The [`DataContract` attribute is not supposed to be inherited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx). So JSON.NET's implementation is not consistent with the proper use of the attribute.